# Shell Scripting using sh. file, display total amount of substrings

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh

1. Download to YOUR computer the file:
    http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~mrobi002/downloads/HumanGenome/VenterGraig/VGuncompressed/hs_alt_HuRef_chr10.fa
2. Create a sh file called `lastName` + `firstInitial` + `pgm4.sh`
3. In the sh file of question 2, Find out and display the total amount of `TTT` substrings found in the first 2,000 lines in the file in question 1.

I know how to create the sh file with TOUCH. 
I understand that a possible command is `wc -c filename`  but how do I write it into the sh file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard editor vi (`vi yourfile`) to edit the file. As an more simple alternitiv use nano (`nano yourfilename`).

Comment: You can also use `emacs`, `vim`, `joe`, `mcedit`, `kedit`, `kate`, etc.

Comment: It's so obvious now, haha. I was gonna use Vi, I ended up using nano. I knew I had to grep. Thank you so much!!

Comment: It seems I'm having problems still, cause its not counting the sub-strings. It seems to be counting the strings.  It's just counting the letters, the strings. Including things that are not T's.

Comment: Okay! I see the tweaked version. I will go with that. My classmates and I are arguing cause got different answers. When I ran it, I got 109,624 and I'm sticking to it. haha

Comment: Hmm. I found out that this method you showed me is actually counting all the strings. It's not counting the sub-strings.  It's supposed to count the groups of TTT. Not just a single T.  The number 109,624 may be too large for just 2,000 lines.

Comment: your right, i fixed the issue. Before it took the whole file, sorry

Answer (score 0):

To count the "TTT"s in the file you can use:

`#!/bin/bash
wget "http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~mrobi002/downloads/HumanGenome/VenterGraig/VGuncompressed/hs_alt_HuRef_chr10.fa" 
head -n2000 hs_alt_HuRef_chr10.fa | sed s/"TTT"/" TTT "/ > file.tmp
grep -c TTT file.tmp && rm file.tmp`